# How to include asp.net user control in .htm pages

Tags: asp.net

I am creating one website where all pages are creating in html but dynamic pages are creating in asp.net. I have one problem in my all static html pages i want to display one user control in one form but pages are .html thats why pages do not support asp.net control. How can i do pls let me khnow if anybody know.

Comment: put that control in an aspx page separate and show that page using  iFrame

Comment: If you can use jQuery, it can be simple. If relevant let me know and I'll give sample code. Please use `@` to notify when you reply here e.g. @Shadow otherwise I won't see you replied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, unless you use an iframe which contains an asp.net page containing the user control.

Furthermore, if it is possible, I don't think this approach should be used. It would make more sense to convert the .htm files to .aspx files, and use rewriting to display them as .htm if this is needed.

Comment: i am using user control for login that login form popuped after clicking of one button if i use iframe then after login i want to another postlogin page that time that page open in that i frame then how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't. Html pages don't get processed by your ASP.NET engine. You could change them into .aspx files, and include the control, preferably within the form-tag of the asp.net page.

Comment: if i convert that pages into .aspx then there any problem related to time for loading pages thanks.